# Get data from array based on time intervals

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this,

```
const data =[
    { date: 2022-04-11T15:08:54.223Z, coordinates: [Object] },
    { date: 2022-04-11T15:09:36.078Z, coordinates: [Object] },
    { date: 2022-04-11T15:18:18.405Z, coordinates: [Object] },
    { date: 2022-04-11T15:19:45.228Z, coordinates: [Object] },
    { date: 2022-04-11T15:21:00.188Z, coordinates: [Object] },
]
```

I want to return data based on time intervals, that is like, say the interval is 2 minutes and the time of the first element is 11:00 am then only the elements of the array with time 11:02 am, 11:04 am, 11:06 am. etc. If the interval is 3 minutes, then elements with time 11:03 am, 11:06 am... should be returned. I have tried different methods. It is not working. Can you guys help me with a solution with more efficiency?

If you didn't understand my question,

**Elements in the array**

```
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:39:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:40:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:41:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:42:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:43:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:44:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:45:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:46:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**If I set the time interval as 2 minutes**

*The records should be returned like this*

```
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:39:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:41:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:43:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Element  :: Mon Apr 11 2022 20:45:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: "I have tried different methods. It is not working."  Different methods such as? You should provide examples of what's not working for you and WHY it's not working.

Comment: I have added the function which is not efficient

Comment: I think I have made everything clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a reduce method makes this pretty simple

```
let interval = 3, 
  firstDate;
let intervalArr = data.reduce((acc,entry)=>{
 let date = new Date(entry.date) // should condition this in case prop is a string and not datetime, but should work as is
 firstDate ||= date
 let minutesSinceFirst = ~~((firstDate - date) / 60000) 

 // modulus will be 0 if min is divisible by interval
 if (minutesSinceFirst % interval === 0)
   acc.push(entry)  // push to accumulator

 return acc
}, []) // accumulator starts as an empty array

firstDate = null
```

Comment: using `getMinutes` is a good way to avoid subsecond differences throwing off the match but does throw up other issues ie say you set the sample rate to 35minutes, with your code you would only get the 35th minute of each hour not every 35th minutes reading

Comment: good point, made a quick update

Comment: add a math.floor around the /60000 and i think you've fixed it

Comment: The first one worked for me. This is not working.

Comment: @MikeT heh, forgot that, thank you :) should be fine now

Comment: @AromalA when he fixed it i think he added a typo `first Date` is almost certainly meant to be `firstDate`, if you haven't corrected that it may be why its not working

Comment: not easy typing on the phone :p

Comment: firstDate ||= date  let minutesSinceFirst = ~~((firstDate - date) / 60000) these two lines were the problem. I used the first solution. @zergski,@MikeT Thank you. You saved me a lot of time. Much appreciated